# How to get MIMEText to render HTML?

Tags: python, django, mime

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong with MIMEText. The emails are still sending as plain text. The email body that the user receives looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html;
charset="us-ascii" MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>Thanks for signing up. Go to <a href=localhost:8000/confirm>confirm</a> to complete your registration.</html>
```

(In this example it links to localhost, but in production it will be to my site)

Here is the relevant code from my views.py file:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mailer

def signup(request):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email_address = request.user.email
        mail_subject =  'Welcome!'
        msg = u'<html>Thanks for signing up. Go to <a href=localhost:8000/confirm>confirm</a> to complete your registration.</html>'
        print(msg)
        html_msg = MIMEText(msg, 'html')
        send('myemail@gmail.com', 'myemailpassword', email_address, mail_subject, html_msg)
```

And here is the email sender module, mailer.py:

```
import smtplib

def send(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print('successfully sent the mail')
    except Exception as e:
        print("\n\nfailed to send mail, here's why:\n")
        print(e)
```

Thank you for any help at all here.

Comment: Why are you doing this with smtplib directly, rather than using Djangos' send_mail function?

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mail) for `send_mail()`. Also I'm not sure an <html> without <body> will actually render correctly in email clients.